# Document upload asp.net site with user options to reupload updated document at later time

Tags: c#, file-upload

I going to be starting a project soon that will require users to submit multiple documents for approval to get access to our sensitive data.  These documents once submitted are reviewed by management and then if updates are required the users are notified of this and then they must update their documents and re-submit the documents that needed updating.  I have been forced in prior projects to use older approaches to my projects.  I want to make sure for this project to use the best approach currently available.

Software I'm using:

```
Web Server: Windows Server 2016 standard
 Dev Tools: Visual Studio 2019 (C#)
```

The documents being uploaded have sensitive information.  What is the most secure way to upload and re-upload documents?

Thank you

Comment: I think you minimize the scope of this question as logins are one thing and document upload is another

Comment: Should I make them 2 separate questions?

Comment: I'm not sure your question involves oracle. Removing that and focusing on how to upload with C# in secure manner is a better focus

Comment: Thanks kevinsky, I have minimized the scope of the question to only include the document upload and re-upload process.